How to fix kitchen sink leaking at threaded connector?
When I turn on the kitchen sink faucet, water streams out of a connector under the sink, about a cup a minute.  I see the water coming out on the threaded connector identified by an arrow.  The faucet has a flex hose that must be connected to that threaded connector. (See photos below.)
What is the threaded connector called and how might I try to fix it?
P.S. I am not sure my question is related to this one: Leak in kitchen sink hose



That's a really old faucet, but you may be able to salvage it.

Loosen the set screw. ( blue line)  and then unscrew the hose by gripping the connector to the threaded fitting, ( yellow body).
When the hose is off look inside the fitting, it should have a washer or O-ring that can be replaced.  Add a little Thread sealerto the threads and reinstall in the opposite sequence.
